# Add code in page base to header C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, head

I have the following code in my MasterPageBase.cs file:

```
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = Request.Path;
        var page = _ContentPageRepository.GetContentPageByUrl(url, ConfigurationManager.GetSiteID());
        if (page != null)
        {
            PageBase.SetTitle(page.Title);
            PageBase.SetDescription(page.Description);
            PageBase.SetKeywords(page.Keywords);
        }
        else
        {
            this.ProcessSiteMap();
        }

        this.AddGACode(); 
        base.OnLoad(e); 
    }
```

I need `this.AddGACode();` to get added to the head section of the page, but when I view the source of the page as I am running the solution, I see that this is adding it to the body section of the page.

I have tried `Page.Header.Controls.Add(AddGACode());` and get the following errors:
`The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments` and `cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Web.UI.Control'`

What can I do to get this code added to the head? TIA

EDIT: Request to see the AddGACode method:

```
        private void AddGACode()
    {
        var gaCode = SiteManager.GetSite().GoogleAnalyticsCode;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gaCode) && Response.StatusCode == 200)
        {
            if (!ConfigurationManager.EnableUniversalGATracking)
            {
                ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
                StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
                csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                csText.Append(String.Format("var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{0}']); ", gaCode));
                csText.Append("_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })();");
                csText.Append("</script>");
                cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "GACode", csText.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
                StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
                csText.Append("<!-- Universal GA Code --><script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                csText.Append(String.Concat("(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', '", gaCode,  " ', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview');"));
                csText.Append("</script>");
                cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "GACode", csText.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

This code is in the AddGACode method. There is still `this.AddGACode();` in the `OnLoad` of the page that seems to duplicate the code with this edit, but both codes will disappear if I delete `this.AddGACode();` from `OnLoad`

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
csText.Append("<!-- Universal GA Code --><script type=\"text/javascript\">");
csText.Append(String.Concat("(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', '", gaCode,  " ', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview');"));
csText.Append("</script>");
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "GACode", csText.ToString());
LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(csText.ToString());
Page.Header.Controls.Add(lc);
```

Comment: Let us see `AddGACode`.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the original post.

Comment: I assume this will help: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/Jan/02/Rendering-ASPNET-Script-References-into-the-Html-Header

Comment: I don't think I can help with specifics but the issue is that `AddGACode` returns void but you try to assign the result of it to `Page.Header.Controls`. Your method should return a control if you're going to assign it to a collection of controls.

Comment: Since it's not technically a control, just a method that gets called, is there any other way of making sure the Google Analytics code goes into the head of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds the script into the head tag:

```
        LiteralControl lt = new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('test');</script>");
        Header.Controls.Add(lt);
```

**UPDATE**

```
LiteralControl lt = new LiteralControl(AddGACode());
Header.Controls.Add(lt);
```

...

```
private string AddGACode()
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    var gaCode = SiteManager.GetSite().GoogleAnalyticsCode;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gaCode) && Response.StatusCode == 200)
    {
        StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
        csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        if (!ConfigurationManager.EnableUniversalGATracking)
        {
            csText.Append(String.Format("var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{0}']); ", gaCode));
            csText.Append("_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })();");
        }
        else
        {
            csText.Append(String.Concat("(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', '", gaCode,  " ', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview');"));
        }
        csText.Append("</script>");
        result = csText.ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: When I add this, it starts adding the code twice to the page. What am I doing wrong? Edited original post.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using a break point to check how many times your code goes through those lines and why.

Comment: Well it looks like because I added this to the `AddGACode` method and still have the `this.AddGACode();` called in the `OnLoad` of the page it is being added twice. However, when I delete the code from `OnLoad` of the page, both codes disappear.

Comment: mmm remove the script manager calls in AddGACode, just generate the script and put it into the literal (updated my answer with an example of this).

Comment: Thanks for liking my answer, but it's considered bad form to reproduce it in your own. By all means mention my answer, but please don't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep your markup, in this instance your ga scripts, on mastpage itself. In the `head` tag add two literals, `gaGaq` and `gaUniversal` an then use you logic to contol the visibility of them.

```
<head runat="server"><script type="text\javascript">
       <asp:Literal id="gaGaq" runat="server">
             <!-- Put you gaq code here-->
             <!-- Keep {0} as a place holder for gaqCode -->
             </script>
       </asp:Literal>
       <asp:Literal id="gaUniveral" runat="server">
            <script type="text\javascrtip">
            <!-- Put you universal code here-->
            <!-- Keep {0} as a place holder for gaqCode -->
            </script>
       </asp:Literal>
</head>
```

C#

```
private void AddGACode()
{
    var gaCode = SiteManager.GetSite().GoogleAnalyticsCode;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gaCode) && Response.StatusCode == 200)
    {
        if(ConfigurationManager.EnableUniversalGATracking)
        {   
            //Set gaCode
            gaUniversal.Text = string.Fomat(gaUniveral.Text, gaCode);
        }
        else
        {  
            //Set gaCode             
            gaGaq.Text = string.Format(ga.Text, gaCode);
        }

        gaUniversal.Visible = ConfigurationManager.EnableUniversalGATracking;
        gaGaq.Visible = !ConfigurationManager.EnableUniversalGATracking;
    }
    else
    {
       //Hide Both literals if no gaCode
       gaUniversal.Visible = gaGaq.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

You could also look at putting all this into a custom control. If you're interested in taking that route I wrote a [blog article](http://www.dysfunctionalspec.net/2011/08/08/simple-google-analytics-asp-net-control/) on exactly that for the `gaq` style google analytics so I could drop it onto my many asp.net websites. The code in that article owuld need to be modified to suite your needs but should be enough to get you stared.

Comment: This code is shared by 300+ websites, so it will need to stay in the MasterPageBase, otherwise I will have a lot of Master Pages to update. :/ But that is useful information! If I find a site I can use this on, I definitely will!

Comment: @jlg thats because I missed the part where it was a base class for masterpages!